# StackView constraints with UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uistackview

I'm trying to setup a stackview in the middle of the screen with a padding of 20 to the left an right. Inside, I want to place two custom UIViews, but I don't quit understand how to do it. I tried giving the UIViews their respective Height's and Width's but I got nothing.

I believe the stack view has all the correct constraints. Here's the code:

```
func setupTeamViews() {
    view.addSubview(teamsStackView)
    
    teamsStackView.distribution = .fill
    teamsStackView.axis = .vertical
    teamsStackView.spacing = 20
    teamsStackView.alignment = .fill
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        teamsStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        teamsStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        teamsStackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        teamsStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 420)
    ])
    
    let height = CGFloat((teamsStackView.frame.height / 2) - 20)
    let width = CGFloat((teamsStackView.frame.width - 20))
    
    firstTeamView = ATTeamView(width: width, height: height)
    firstTeamView.changeColor(color: .lightBlue)
    firstTeamView.setTeamName(name: "Tobias")
    firstTeamView.setNewPoints(points: "0")
    
    secondTeamView = ATTeamView(width: width, height: height)
    secondTeamView.changeColor(color: .white)
    secondTeamView.setTeamName(name: "Valen")
    secondTeamView.setNewPoints(points: "0")
    
    teamsStackView.addArrangedSubview(firstTeamView)
    teamsStackView.addArrangedSubview(secondTeamView)
}
```

How does a stackview work with UIview's? As far I understand, UIViews don't have **intrinsicContentSize**, but I don't know how to deal with that.

Comment: If you are adding UIViews inside of stackview, you need to check distribution property in attribute inspector. Stackview take care of width and height of the child views

Comment: Ideally you don't need to provide width and height constraints of the child views.

Comment: If you want your chid views to have a particular size when arranged by the stack, you can subclass a UIView (or any subclass of UIView) and override intrinsicContentSize, returning the size it wants (possiby just returning current bounds, if that's what you're after). Then just let the stack view arrange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code wasn't working because I've forgotten to set `teamsStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Answer (score 0):

In stead of doing it programmatically you can add two container views attach them to your view controller, and then active them with the alpha.

This will make constraints easier and you can still program anything extra you would like

```
myView1.alpha = 1 // activate
myView2.alpha = 0 // deactivate
```